# Не могу установить ни один сторонний браузер в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, браузер

Были попытки установить xulrunner и Awersomium.
Xulrunner устанавливал по вот этой инструкции - http://habrahabr.ru/post/170015/

Awersomium устанавливал файлом с оффсайта, он самораспаковывающийся. В итоге:

Xulrunner не запускается, выдает Exception с таким сообщением:

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Skybound.Gecko, Version=1.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3209ac31600d1857" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Менял в настройках проекта версию .NET на 2.0 - то же самое.
На форме панель panel1 и кнопка с кодом:

```
 string path = Application.StartupPath + @"\\FF 1.9\\";   //Путь к распакованной и переименованной папке bin из архива SDK
        Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(path);
        Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser webBrowser1 = new Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser();
        webBrowser1.Parent = this.panel1;
        webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        string u = "http://www.ya.ru";

        //Загрузка выбранной страницы
        webBrowser1.Navigate(u);
```

Awersomium добавился в панель элементов, но при попытке бросить на форму WebControl, выдает ошибку, которая на скриншоте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чем проблема, помогите.

На данный момент цель установки другого браузера - это работа каждого отдельного объекта браузера через свой прокси, если есть какие-то решения - предлагайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Это ошибка из-за попытки загрузить сборку, скомпилированную под другую платформу - другую битность. Т.е. или сборка у вас для x86, а вы пытаетесь загрузить ее в 64-битное приложение, или наоборот.

Откройте свойства своего проекта, закладку Build.

Найдите там чекбокс Prefer 32-Bit. Его можен не быть в старой версии студии. Если есть - снимите его.

Потом найдите там же дропдаун с настройкой Platform Target. Скорее всего она выставлена в Any CPU. Поменяйте на x86. Попробуйте запустить. Если упадет - поменяйте на x64. Один из двух вариантов должен заработать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, действительно заработало!
А что скажете про Awersomium?

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко скорее всего тоже не хватает какой-то сборки. пройдитесь по мануалу http://wiki.awesomium.net/getting-started/setting-up-on-windows.html - там кроме просто референса надо еще пачку нативных dll добавлять